# Can you say "trader TO decorated wooden crockery"?

Tags: prepositions

Can you say "trader TO decorated wooden crockery"?

Or "of"? Or better "dealer of"

Comment: "Crockery" tends to imply that it's made out of ceramics... "wooden crockery" sounds very odd to me.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, "trader" most commonly takes the preposition **in**, occasionally **of**, but never **to**:

> He is a trader in decorated wooden crockery.
>
> She is a trader of decorated wooden crockery.

Comment: Not so - [*He is a **dealer in** X*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+is+a+trader+in%2CHe+is+a+dealer+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20is%20a%20trader%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHe%20is%20a%20dealer%20in%3B%2Cc0) has always been far more common than ***trader***. But both are relatively unusual compared to ***He deals in X***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - The question I answered (Can you say "trader TO decorated wooden crockery"?)  was specific to the verb _to trade_, and what preposition it commonly takes. I overlooked the second part.

Comment: Hmm. If we disregard the possibility of using some variant of ***deal*** rather than ***trade***, I think *is the most common usage* is perhaps a misleading way of comparing the prepositional usages *trader **in** X* and *trader **to** X* (to all intents and purposes, the latter simply isn't valid at all, let alone "less common").

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've tinkered with it. It's interesting that we can use _of_ with the noun form, but not the verb: we can say "trader of," but never" "he trades of."

Comment: Following your edit, I'm more that happy to *reverse* my downvote. That does mean your answer now has more upvotes than @Kevin's (even though I think it should be important for OP to know that ***deal/dealer*** are far more commonly used in this context). But I doubt the mods will delete my first comment above, so it's all here one way or another.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was about to deal with _deal_, but Kevin already dealt with it. I'll tinker some more when I have some time.

Answer (score 2):

No, you would not say "trader to".

Both "trader of" and "dealer of" are acceptable, but as FumbleFingers points out, and this [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trader%20to%20goods%2Ctrader%20of%20goods%2Cdealer%20of%20goods%2C%20deals%20in%20goods&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrader%20of%20goods%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdealer%20of%20goods%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeals%20in%20goods%3B%2Cc0) shows, "deals in" is more common than either of them/

Answer (score 1):

Trader or dealer of decorated wooden crockery are acceptable. You might consider

> decorated wooden crockery dealer

or trader.